# Speakers make a pop sound on boot [Huawei MateBook D 14 Ryzen EU-Version]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound, music

so I recently bought the notebook and I am currently dual-booting Windows 10 and ElementaryOS 5.0. The system runs flawlessly except for when I boot into elementaryOS my speakers make a loud pop-noise and my screen has a visual interference (like a colorful TV-noise image) in the top third of the screen.
Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware issue and not related to the Music app

Answer (score 0):

I have a Matebook D too, and mine do the same beahaviors than you. I don't think it's important, as far as I remember it has always done that, and it never appears apart of the boot.